# How can I check the position of \"results\":[{ in a string?

Tags: c#

I am familiar with the use of .IndexOf("xxx", 0)

But how can I check for the position of a string that contains both backslashes and quotation marks?

Here's what I need to check for the position of:  `\"results\":[{`

Comment: Please add some example ;).

Comment: If you're parsing JSON, use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have escape those characters, which mean putting `\` before them:

```
.indexOf("\\\"results\\\":[{")
```

For more information take a look at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) which explains escape sequences.